# What is the terminology for $a$ in $x>a$?

Tags: terminology, number-comparison

In an expression like $$x>a,$$ what do I call $a$? And how to distinguish it from $b$ in $$x\geq b.$$ Is there some standard terminology?

Comment: You can say $a$ is a *strict lower bound* for $x$, and $b$ is (just) a *lower bound* for $x$. But I am not sure if calling $a$ *strict* is appropriate here.

Comment: A lower bound usually means $x\geq b$. One says that this lower bound is *tight*, if there is no bigger lower bound than $b$. But to be honest, I never read and a quick google does not show any use of the term *strict* in this place. Maybe one can say $a$ is *strictly dominated* by $x$ or $x$ is *strictly dominating* $a$.

Comment: I don't understand why this has been so quickly downvoted with no explanations.

Comment: I also wonder. Maybe one can enhance the title. I will try.

Comment: I suspect that OP is looking for terms corresponding to things like "multiplier" and "multiplicand" or "dividend" and "divisor", but I could be wrong. For dominance relations like these, I know of no such terms, but "lower bound" doesn't seem to me to have the right *sense*. although I grant that it's strictly speaking correct. But "right operand" and "number" might also be correct without really capturing the sense of things.

Comment: @JohnHughes: French has the words *minorant* and *majorant*. Don't know if there are English equivalents.

Comment: @JohnHughes I guess one would refer to $x$ or to $a$ (or $b$) as the *left hand side* and the *right hand side* of the inequality respectively, and to the former inequality as a *strict* one.

Comment: @M.Winter but that doesn't work for $a<x$. I'd like the same word for $a$ as it would be called in $x>a$

Comment: I see. I like Yves french versions and it might be that I also read them in english texts.

Comment: @Yves: Wow! I like those. If we don't have them, we should adopt them (as we have so many others).

Comment: Google and a dictionary or two suggest we DO have those words, they're seldom used, and are perfect for the task. (Then again, when was the last time you used "subtrahend"? I guess limited use doesn't mean 'useless word'.)

Comment: Minorant seems to be functions specifically in English. From what I can understand, $f: x \mapsto x$ is a minorant of $g: x\mapsto x+1$

Comment: @JohnHughes: mh, this raises another question: in a comparison, which is the comparhend and which the comparator ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Extracting from the comments:

I think that the words "majorant" (for $x$) and "minorant" (for $a$) would suffice, and that you could use "strict majorant" for $x$ in in $x > a$ and "weak majorant" when you only know that $x \ge a$, but those might be confusing to a reader.

In fact, if I were writing something like this, I'd say

"So we see that $x > a$. Calling $x$ the "majorant" and $a$ the minorant in such expressions, we more generally see that ..."

i.e., give an inline gloss on the words you want to use henceforth.

Comment: Minorant seems to be functions specifically in English (from some googling). From what I can understand, $f: x \mapsto x$ is a minorant of $g: x\mapsto x+1$

Comment: Agreed. But giving a gloss inline probably allows the use of the word in this context (one could treat both $x$ and $a$ as constant functions of some hidden parameter $t$, for instance).